# Why is it allowed to create multiple copies of String when they are immutable?

Tags: java, string, immutability

In Java, I could create multiple String with the same value as the new operator.
But since strings are immutable. What's the point of allowing multiple String.
Why not keep even the ones created with the new operator in String pool and save memory.

Comment: Immutable just means that the object that holds the characters can't be changed.  For multiple copies, you have different objects.  If you change one string to another you are always making a new object, not changing the original.  To check that a String is already interned in the pool before copying could involve extra, unwarranted overhead.  But if you assign the same literals to strings they should always be the same object.

Comment: Note that the documentation for the `String()` and `String(String)` constructors both state “use of this constructor is unnecessary.”

Answer (score 0):

The "point" is consistency of behaviour of the language. The `new` operator always makes a new object. No exceptions.

Is it desirable to create a new String instance every time the `new` operator is invoked, even if the same, identical String already exists? Not really. But the alternative is to have to circumvent the entire constructor mechanism in order to check some kind of object pool before creating a new instance.

Such an object pool would either have to be a special exception made just for the String class, or object pools would have to somehow be definable at the class level (some kind of special constructor). Both of those are relatively undesirable as well because of the additional complexity.

As it stands, the String constant pool and String interning provide enough protection against millions of duplicate String objects, **without** introducing huge amounts of additional complexity to the language.